Pydantic model for representing datetime as date and time
I have created a Pydantic model for datetime that will handle parsing a JSON object that looks like { "date": "2021-07-01", "time": "12:36:23" } into datetime(2021, 7, 1, 12, 36, 23). It also generates the correct JSON Schema for the model.
class TimestampWithSplit(RootModel):
    root: datetime

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, source: Type[Any], handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        return core_schema.chain_schema(
            [
                core_schema.typed_dict_schema(
                    {
                        "date": core_schema.typed_dict_field(core_schema.date_schema()),
                        "time": core_schema.typed_dict_field(core_schema.time_schema()),
                    }
                ),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate_to_datetime),
            ]
        )

    @staticmethod
    def validate_to_datetime(value: dict) -> datetime:
        return datetime.combine(value["date"], value["time"])

I'm trying to now do two things:

I now want to add descriptions to the generated json schema. Currently TimestampWithSplit.model_json_schema() returns

{'properties': {'date': {'format': 'date', 'title': 'Date', 'type': 'string'},
                'time': {'format': 'time', 'title': 'Time', 'type': 'string'}},
 'required': ['date', 'time'],
 'type': 'object'}

and I want to add
{'properties': {'date': {'format': 'date', 'title': 'Date', 'type': 'string', 'description': 'ISO format date, blah blah'},
                'time': {'format': 'time', 'title': 'Time', 'type': 'string', 'description': 'ISO format time, blah blah'}},
 'required': ['date', 'time'],
 'type': 'object'}


Add a custom validator for the date field so it can parse single digit day and month numbers. I'd normally do this like this:

    def validator(value: str):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        except ValueError:
            return None

and add that validator as a plain validator on the field. But I'm not sure how to incorporate that into what I've got.
Am I going down the wrong path? How do I have a model that has date and time as separate fields but returns a datetime from model_validate_json while also customising the JSON schema and date validation?

I may be unclear on your goal, so I apologize if this isn't applicable, but it looks like you would be better off using a BaseModel with date and time properties rather than using your RootModel solution. Given code like this:
import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, computed_field, field_validator


class TimestampWithSplit(BaseModel):
    date: datetime.date = Field(
        ..., description="ISO format date", repr=False, exclude=True
    )
    time: datetime.time = Field(
        ..., description="ISO format time", repr=False, exclude=True
    )

    @computed_field
    @property
    def timestamp(self) -> datetime.datetime:
        return datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.time)

We can initialize it from a dictionary:
>>> t=TimestampWithSplit.model_validate({'date': '2024-09-24', 'time': '11:00:00'})
>>> t
TimestampWithSplit(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 24, 11, 0))

We can initialize it using keyword parameters:
>>> t=TimestampWithSplit(date='2024-09-24', time='11:00:00')
>>> t
TimestampWithSplit(timestamp=datetime.datetime(2024, 9, 24, 11, 0))

If you wanted to support single digit months/days, like 2024-9-1, you could add a field validator for the date field. Maybe something like this:
@field_validator("date", mode="before")
@classmethod
def validate_date(cls, v: str | datetime.date) -> datetime.date:
    if isinstance(v, datetime.date):
        return v
    elif isinstance(v, str):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid date")

This gives you the schema you want, including the field descriptions:
>>> print(json.dumps(t.schema(), indent=2))
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "description": "ISO format date",
      "format": "date",
      "title": "Date",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "time": {
      "description": "ISO format time",
      "format": "time",
      "title": "Time",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "date",
    "time"
  ],
  "title": "TimestampWithSplit",
  "type": "object"
}

And the serialization of this type includes only the combined timestamp field:
>>> t.model_dump_json()
'{"timestamp":"2024-09-24T11:00:00"}'


Yea this is perfect, thank you for pulling me out of the rabbit hole I'd fallen down
